# Why is my fix for making an ICS generator IE compatible rendering another function "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, html, icalendar

I am new to StackOverflow and very much a beginner at Javascript so I apologize if there is an obvious issue with either the code or my post. I'm not necessarily trying to do this in the best or prettiest way at the moment, just get this project working before my internship ends. I have been working  on making this https://github.com/commonpike/add-to-calendar-buttons add to calendar work with internet explorer which is not compatible with Encode:URI or the HTML "Download" attribute.

With the help comments on the project and other fixes to similar problems that I've seen I THOUGHT that I could add this code in the appropriate places and get things working. The calendar function is already part of the code but I included it because it is affected.

```
var href2 = (
  'BEGIN:VCALENDAR',
  'VERSION:2.0',
  'BEGIN:VEVENT',
  'URL:' + document.URL,
  'DTSTART:' + (startTime || ''),
  'DTEND:' + (endTime || ''),
  'SUMMARY:' + (event.title || ''),
  'DESCRIPTION:' + (event.description || ''),
  'LOCATION:' + (event.address || ''),
  'UID:' + (event.id || '') + '-' + document.URL,
  'END:VEVENT',
  'END:VCALENDAR');

if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) {
  return '<a class="' + eClass + '" href="javascript:msDownloadCalendar(\'' +
    href2 + '\')">' + calendarName + '</a>';
} else {
  return '<a class="' + eClass + '" download="' + CONFIG.texts.download + '" href="' +
    href + '">' + calendarName + '</a>';
}
},

exports.msDownloadCalendar = function(url) {
  if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) {
    var blob = new Blob([href2], {
      type: 'text/calendar;charset=utf-8'
    });
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'download.ics');
  }
};

exports.addToCalendar = function(params) {
  if (params instanceof HTMLElement) {
    //console.log('HTMLElement');
    return parseCalendar(params);
  }

  if (params instanceof NodeList) {
    //console.log('NodeList');
    var success = (params.length > 0);
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(params, function(node) {
      success = success && addToCalendar(node);
    });
    return success;
  }

  sanitizeParams(params);

  if (!validParams(params)) {
    console.log('Event details missing.');
    return;
  }

  return generateMarkup(
    generateCalendars(params.data),
    params.options.class,
    params.options.id
  );
};
```

This does not however fix the problem. While it has no effect on the functionality in other browsers it totally breaks it in IE as only the headers show up while the console says the function 'addtocalendar' is undefined. 'Addtocalender' only logs as undefined in IE so I have to assume something that is being brought into play by

`if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true ))`

is the culprit.

Thank you so so much to anyone in the community who can give me some input and help me get this up and running. I've pushed my head against the wall about at much as I can with my current skill set, and have learned a lot, but fear I have reached my my current limit.

Comment: What are you expecting `var href2 = (list of comma-separated items);` to do? It's essentially equivalent to `var href2 = 'END:VCALENDAR';` because the comma operator just returns the last value.

Comment: What are `eClass` and `calendarName`? Where do you set them?

Comment: I intended var href2 to have the same string of items as the var href in the original file which was the same but had:
 ```var href = encodeURI(
        'data:text/calendar;charset=utf8,' + [``` before it and after ```].join('\n'));```
I did this as I needed the info within but as encodeURI isnt supported In IE I thought this would be the easiest way of grabbing the info from var href. 

For eClass and calendarName both are elsewhere in the linked file. It works well on other browsers.I again apologize for glaring flaws as I am a novice trying to brute force things into preexisting code.